# Word coordinates with pdfminer

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, document-layout-analysis

I am trying to write a pdf layout analyzer in python. I have been able to produce some fairly decent results using Pandas for the work. However, so far I have been using data generated by JPedal, but the coordinates produced seem to contain some considerable inaccuracies, that are affecting the final result. At the moment I am working with data that is represented in a Pandas DF like this:

```
          font  page           style words   x1   x2   y1   y2
0  Times-Roman     1  font-size:22pt     K  206  214  120  144
1  Times-Roman     1  font-size:22pt     O  226  234  120  144
2  Times-Roman     1  font-size:22pt     H  245  253  120  144
```

Now I am thinking about trying to use pdfminer to produce data that contains the same basic attributes. As I understand I should be using pdfminer layout objects to get this data. Unfortunately the documentation is a bit vague. Pointers to solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, which tool did you use to get the output above?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using PDFMiner on a project simply by using it's command-line tool to produce XML, and using the coordinates from there.

This gets the coordinates of individual characters - I'm doing my own layout analysis from there, as I didn't find the built-in analysis to work well enough on my document.